# Inner Product Spaces and Minimum Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

> **Problem**
>
> Let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$ endowed with the inner product
>
> $$ (f,g)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}f(x)g(x)dx $$
>
> By considering the series of subspaces $\{V_n\}$ where $V_n=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]: \deg(f) \leq n\}$ or otherwise, show that there exist unique monic polynomials $\varphi_n(x)$ for $n \geq 0$ such that
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}\varphi_n(x)g(x)dx=0$$ whenever deg
>   $g<n$, and find $\varphi_n(x)$ for $n=0,1,2$.

**Progress**

We look to identify $(V_n)^{\perp}$ for  each $n$, i.e.

$$(V_n)^{\perp}=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]: \langle f,g \rangle=0 \text{ for all } g \in V_n\}$$

If we can show this has dimension $1$, then we can show the existence of a unique monic polynomial. Any thoughts on how this is done (or an alternative method for the problem) would be greatly appreciated. Regards.

Comment: I think there's a condition missing for unicity, namely $\deg \varphi_n = n$. Stated otherwise $V_n^{\perp}$ is **not** one-dimensional (it's infinite-dimensional), but $V_n^{\perp} \cap V_{n+1}$ is.

Comment: @JoelCohen: Apologies, it should read $V_n=\{f(x) \in
 \mathbb{R}[X]: deg(f) \leq n\}$. I'll make the edit now. I don't think it's a condition for the degree to be n, but it may well be the case.

Comment: Offsetting indices does not change the fact that $V_n^{\perp}$ is not finite-dimensional (let alone one-dimensional). In fact, if $V$ is **any** finite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]$, then $V^{\perp}$ is infinite dimensional. For example, you can check that $V_0^{\perp}$ contains $X^{2n+1}$ for all $n \le 0$.

Comment: @JoelCohen: I'm assuming that this is the best way to approach the question, it may be that considering the orthogonal complement is heading in the wrong direction. I see your point though - thanks!

Comment: For existence I'd use [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process) on $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ first, then normalize appropriately to ensure that the polynomial becomes monic. Uniqueness will become clear afterwards.

Comment: @t.b.: Hadn't occurred to me! I'll try it now. Thanks.

Comment: @TJO : I think you made progress in the right direction : your interpretation in terms of orthogonal complement is the right one, and the fact that you have to prove some space is one-dimensional to prove unicity is also spot on. The only problem is that you're missing a condition to conclude (because $V_n^{\perp}$ is actually infinite dimensional). If you require $\deg \varphi_n = n$, then you'll be able to proceed with your idea.

Comment: @JoelCohen: I think if we simply state that the Gram-Schmidt process can be applied to the linearly independent set $\{1, X, X^2, \ldots, X^n \}$ for each n and then use the final vector yielded as our $\varphi_n$ then we should be fine, as the inner product of $\varphi_n$ with any linear combination of the previous vectors yielded will always be zero. The process can then be used to explicitly calculate the vectors.

Comment: @TJO : Yes, the Gram-Schmidt process yields the solution which satisfies $\deg \varphi_n = n$ (because from the Gram-Schmidt process, we have $\textrm{Span}(\varphi_0, \ldots, \varphi_n) = \textrm{Span}(X^0, \ldots, X^{n}) = V_{n}$ so $\deg \varphi_n \le n$, but from the orthagonality condition, $\deg \varphi_n \ge n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem should remind you of Gram-Schmidt, but if you are interested in showing only the existence (and uniqueness) of the $\varphi_n$, and not interested in the final formula, then one can stop short of all the calculations. That said, I recommend that you are not as lazy as I am; the calculations might end up illuminating. :)

All one needs to understand is the abstract operation of *orthogonal projection*. Consider a vector space $V$ and a finite dimensional subspace $E \subseteq V$. Then the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $E$ is the unique vector $w \in E$ such that $v - w \perp E$. It is a standard fact that such a projection always exists and is unique; let us denote this $\operatorname{Proj}(v, E)$.

If you know this fact (or take it for granted), then this problem is easy: 
$$
\varphi_n(x) = x^n - \operatorname{Proj}(x^n, V_{n-1})
$$
is the unique monic polynomial of degree $n$ such that $(\varphi_n, g) = 0$ for all $g \in V_{n-1}$. (Note that the projection, being in $V_{n-1}$, is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.) Now, it is an altogether a different matter how to evaluate the projection term. It does not come out to be a nice expression, and moreover, it's not at all clear to me that it is intended here.

---

To complete the picture, let us also see why the projection as defined always exists and is unique.

**Uniqueness.** Suppose there exist $w_1, w_2 \in E$ such that $v - w_1 \perp E$ and $v - w_2 \perp E$. Then $w_1 - w_2 = (v - w_2) - (v- w_1)$ is also orthogonal to $E$. In particular, since $w_1 - w_2$ itself is in $E$, it is orthogonal to itself; that is, $w_1 - w_2 = 0$. Thus the projection -- when it exists -- is unique.

**Existence.** Since $E$ is a finite dimensional real* inner product vector space, it possesses an orthonormal basis. Let $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_r$ be such an orthonormal basis, where $r = \dim E$. Then the projection of a given vector  can simply be written down as:
$$
w = \operatorname{Proj}(v, E) := \sum_{i=1}^r (v, u_i) u_i.
$$
It is easy to see that $v-w$ is orthogonal to each basis vector $u_i$, and hence is orthogonal to the whole subspace $E$.

Of course, if, in a concrete setting, we want to find the projection, we should compute an orthonormal basis for $E$. This is usually done using the Gram-Schmidt process, as was alluded to in the comments.

---

*I assume real base field; the complex case is not too different.